# Can't import from com.android.support libraries. +Different versions?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am quite new in Android development and stumbled upon this problem: Even though i have imported the android.support-libraries, I can't import them in my activities. For instance I get 'Cannot resolve symbol 'AppCompatActivity'.
The same error is with all these in my main activity:

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

My build.gradle look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lalalala.alalala"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
}
```

There is a red line under 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0' where the issue apparently is that I have different versions of com.android.support libraries. The hint says:
'All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0'

but where does those libraries come from? I don't have that in my dependencies...

Comment: can you post your full gradle file code

Comment: there must be some underlined error in your build.gradle file  where these dependencies already present with new versions. Just exclude them or implement them the same version

Answer (score 0):

Some of android support module had implemented another android support with different version. For solve this you can implemented com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0, or you can exclude them.

Comment: But it still says that I have com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 also if i compile the com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0

Comment: what gradle version do you use? I have gradle version 3.1.3 and got warning like this.
`WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (23.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.3.
`

Answer (score 0):

So after changing my 'compile's to 'implementation' and updating the gradle version (at least that is what I think I did lol) because I got the same warning that Ade Fruandta got, and also syncing the build.gradle while commenting and uncommenting the implementations, it somehow worked.